# I need a PHP regex to match exactly the following

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex for a `preg_match` function that matches the following:

> a2354 - r2343

Where the 5-character strings can be the following:

1st character: any uppercase/lowercase character from the English alphabet.

2nd-5th character: any numerical digit from 0-9.

The first and second group of 5 characters must have a space before and after although the space should include any weird charset characters that present as a space.

There must be a string between them that matches ' - ' (space, dash, space) although the spaces should include any weird characters that could present as a space and the dash should be any character that presents as a dash.

Comment: Is there effort provided to attempt to solve this yourself?

Answer (score 4):

From your description, I think you're looking for:

```
/\s[a-z][0-9]{4}\s-\s[a-z][0-9]{4}\s/i
```

However, it's a little bit unclear. I'll break it down, and then include links to the documentation, so you can fill in the ambiguous parts on your own.

```
1) \s: anything considered a "white-space" character
2) [a-z]: the normal English alphabet (lower/uppercase handled by 'i' flag at the end
3) [0-9]: the normal Euro-centric numerals
4) {4}: repeats exactly 4 times
```

1 is called an [escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php); 2 and 3 are documented at [Character classes](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php); 4 is [repetition](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php). Lastly, the trailing `i` is called a [Pattern modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).